# elasticsearch"java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException: null" by use transportClient

Tags: elasticsearch

Using elasticsearch transportClient find some exceptions:

```
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException: null
at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:127) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:644) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:108) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:70) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:634) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:207) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:229) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:182) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannelsLight(NettyTransport.java:769) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:737) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNodeLight(NettyTransport.java:709) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLight(TransportService.java:154) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:342) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:288) [stormjar.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$ScheduledNodeSampler.run(TransportClientNodesService.java:321) [stormjar.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_71]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
```

Every elasticsearch node config hostname and ip with /etc/hosts

transport use 9300  and http port use 8080

Log level is warning , but I don't know why have these exceptions